# How to send input values in ng-repeat? Ionic

Tags: php, angularjs, post, ionic-framework

i can not send value to my php server from my ionic app. I use this codes in html ;

```
  <form ng-submit="addfavourite()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="veri.mac_id">
      <input type="submit" value="" class="favourite">
  </form>
```

And i try to post some values in my controller ;

```
$scope.veri = {};

$scope.addfavourite = function(){

    var links = 'http://www.example.com/api.php';
    $scope.veri.user_id = loggeduser;
        $http.post(links, {user_id : $scope.veri.user_id, mac_id : $scope.veri.mac_id}).then(function (fav){
        $scope.response = fav.data;
        if ($scope.response == 1) {
          $scope.messages = 'Correct.';
        }
        else if ($scope.response == 0)
        {
          $scope.messages = 'False.';
        }
        console.log($scope.veriler.mac_id);
    });
};
```

I try something to get value of mac_id but i couldn't do. When i looked to the console only "undefined" error displaying.

Comment: Your ng-model is veri.mac_id but you are `console.log`ing veriler.mac_id. That's why it's undefined. How are trying to get it on PHP?

Comment: sorry i forgot to change this because i tried so many things. When i changed to $scope.veri.mac_id and console give "undefined" again.

Comment: How are trying to get it on PHP?

Comment: $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
 if (isset($postdata)) {
  $request = json_decode($postdata);
  $user_mail = $request->user_id;
  $mac_id = $request->mac_id; }   with this code. i can get user_id but mac_id can not post.

Comment: Open the dev tools of your browser and inspect this request. See if the JSON is being sent correctly.

Comment: <div ng-repeat="veri in veriler">
  
  <form ng-submit="addfavourite()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="veri.mac_id">
      <input type="submit" value="" class="favourite">
  </form>

</div>  

i used this form in ng-repeat. it can be the reason of this error? But i can get other values of this JSON correctly and print on the screen in my app. I only can't get in my input.

Comment: Open the dev tools of your browser and inspect this request. See if the JSON is being sent correctly.

Comment: can you tell me how can i inspect the jeson sent or not in my php page? My php page is in my server and there is nothing when i opened and inspect it. Or i understood you wrong?

Comment: Let's suppose you are using Chrome. Before clicking Send, press F12. It will open a Window, know as dev tools. There you can see your request.

https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/network-jpg

Comment: There is no error shown in dev tools. 200 code as ok.

Comment: But, click on the request, and down in the details, you can see the data being sent. Is every thing being sent correctly?

Comment: thanks for your support. I got a screenshot of this page. You can check. I couldn't see about the data sending. https://postimg.org/image/ov3ub89zp/

Comment: updatecode and withthis code i can post manualdata but i can't post bindeddata.
<form>
<input type="text" name="mac_id" ng-model="mac_id" ng-value="veri.mac_id">
<input type="submit" class="favourite" ng-click="addtofavourite(mac_id)">
</form>

    $scope.veri = {};
    $scope.addtofavourite = function(mac_id){
        var link = 'http://example.com/api.php';
        var mac_id = mac_id;
        var user_id = loggeduser;
        alert (mac_id);
        $http.post(link, {user_id : user_id, mac_id : mac_id}).then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;
        });};

Comment: Click in one of the requests to your api. Once you click it, a new section will open next to this one. In there you'll be able to see the data sent.

Comment: I'm sorry but are you learning Ionic without knowing how to use the Developer Tools of a browser? You might be getting ahead of yourself, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

```
  <form>
      <input type="text" ng-model="veri.mac_id">
      <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="favourite" ng-click='addfavourite()'>
  </form>
```

JS

```
$scope.veri = {};
$scope.addfavourite = function(){
alert('DATA TO SEND '+$scope.veri.mac_id);
}
```

you can just modify your code as I wrote bellow. where you add `ng-click` and remove `ng-submit`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried what you said but i get "DATA TO SEND undefined" in alert box. Let me explain more about my issue. I have a list which gets data from my php server in JSON format. I can successfully get data and print to the screen. But i need to make a favourite section and i made a form and add inputs for the values. I send user_id with localstorage and i can get user_id value in my php server successfully. But when i try to send mac_id value always i get undefined errors. I really don't know how can i send binded data from my input to my php server.

Comment: are you typed data into input text?

Comment: normally i bind data into input from JSON. On the screen i can see the data in the inputs. When i try to type manual into input but again i see undefined. Interesting things i use another form in my another pages and i can send manual data correctly. But in this page i can not do.

Comment: updatecode and withthis code i can post manualdata but i can't post bindeddata.
<form>
<input type="text" name="mac_id" ng-model="mac_id" ng-value="veri.mac_id">
<input type="submit" class="favourite" ng-click="addtofavourite(mac_id)">
</form>

    $scope.veri = {};
    $scope.addtofavourite = function(mac_id){
        var link = 'http://example.com/api.php';
        var mac_id = mac_id;
        var user_id = loggeduser;
        alert (mac_id);
        $http.post(link, {user_id : user_id, mac_id : mac_id}).then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;
        });};

Answer (score 0):

You have set up these?
Ionic will send json format, but PHP can not accept json the default.
You will need to set the php receive json format.

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

//Allow all domain names to be accessed
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');

$content_type_args = explode(';', $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']);
if ($content_type_args[0] == 'application/json') {
    $_REQUEST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
};
```

Try it?

```
$scope.addfavourite = function(){

    var user_id = $scope.veri.user_id;
    var mac_id = $scope.veri.mac_id;

    var data = {};
    data.user_id = user_id;
    data.mac_id = mac_id;

    var links = 'http://www.example.com/api.php';

    $http.post(links, data).then(function (fav) {

        $scope.response = fav.data;

        if ($scope.response == 1) {
            $scope.messages = 'Correct.';
        }
        else if ($scope.response == 0) {
            $scope.messages = 'False.';
        }

        console.log($scope.veriler.mac_id); //$scope.veri.mac_id ?

});};
```

Comment: Thanks but my problem is in my app. because i send user_id value to my server and succesfully get but i can not send input value to my server. I bind mac_id data into input and try to send values but always variable is undefined.

Comment: updatecode and withthis code i can post manualdata but i can't post bindeddata.
<form>
<input type="text" name="mac_id" ng-model="mac_id" ng-value="veri.mac_id">
<input type="submit" class="favourite" ng-click="addtofavourite(mac_id)">
</form>

    $scope.veri = {};
    $scope.addtofavourite = function(mac_id){
        var link = 'http://example.com/api.php';
        var mac_id = mac_id;
        var user_id = loggeduser;
        alert (mac_id);
        $http.post(link, {user_id : user_id, mac_id : mac_id}).then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data;
        });};